# ValueError: Image size is zero in Google Colab

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-lite, image-classification

I'm learning ML model training following this [tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sqBewUnvdATOO-yblj55EBFb2sM24XHR#scrollTo=lANoNS_gtdH1) from Tensorflow. I have uploaded my own dataset from my computer to a folder named "sample_arrow" in Google Colab and specified the path to it:

```
image_path = 'sample_arrow'
```

The folder contains images, the size is not 0. But I get an error when executing this line of code:

```
data = DataLoader.from_folder(image_path) train_data, test_data = data.split(0.9)

ValueError: Image size is zero
```

[image]

What is wrong here? Maybe the folder path is not specified correctly? I'm completely new to the topic, unfamiliar with Pyhon (have Java skills) and would appreciate a detailed answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70244407/tensorflow-lite-image-size-is-zero-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I've found the solution.
Import os and the correct path definition were missing:

```
import os


root_path = "/content/"    
image_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(root_path), 'sample_arrow')
```

[image]

Comment: I still getting this error even I set my path correctly. I directly copy and paste the photos path in windows but there is still the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in google colab:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

data_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
      'flower_photos',
      'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz',
      untar=True)


from tflite_model_maker import image_classifier
from tflite_model_maker.image_classifier import DataLoader

# Load input data specific to an on-device ML app.
data = DataLoader.from_folder(data_path)
train_data, test_data = data.split(0.9)

# Customize the TensorFlow model.
model = image_classifier.create(train_data)

# Evaluate the model.
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_data)

# Export to Tensorflow Lite model and label file in `export_dir`.
model.export(export_dir='/tmp/')
```

So you need to download the data! took me a while to find the solution!!